# expected simple_rnn_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 150, 150, 1)

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I try to use rnn to build a image recognize by using tensorflow2.0. As a convenience,i use flow_from_directory to load my image which is 3D and rgb picture.here is my code.

```
keras.layers.SimpleRNN(
            input_shape=(150, 150),  # Or: input_dim=INPUT_SIZE, input_length=TIME_STEPS,
            units=200,
            unroll=True),
        keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)#my code is to recognize dog and cat
])
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,  
                                   horizontal_flip = True  
)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
# Flow training images in batches of 128 using train_datagen generator
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        './tmp/train/',  # This is the source directory for training images
    color_mode='grayscale',
        target_size=(150, 150),  # All images will be resized to 150x150
        # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
        class_mode='binary')
validation_dir='./tmp/validation'
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_dir,
    color_mode='grayscale',
# if we use color_mode='grayscale' 3D -> 1D error message is (32,150,150,3)->(32,150,150,1)
    target_size=(150, 150),
    class_mode='binary'
)
print(model.summary())

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.3),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=3,validation_data=validation_generator,verbose=1)
```

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

simple_rnn (SimpleRNN)       (None, 200)               70200

---

dropout (Dropout)            (None, 200)               0

---

## dense (Dense)                (None, 2)                 402

Comment: RNNs cannot process image data. Use something like `ConvLSTM2D` layer if you need to process time-series image data.

Comment: Error when checking input: expected conv_lst_m2d_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 150, 150, 1)

Comment: I see a lots program which use rnn to process the mnist dataset，but mnist dataset is 1Dpicture，when we use a rgb picture then program will cause errors。when i use     color_mode='grayscale' which does not change the D of tensor which is always 4D (batch_size,weight,high,D)